# Struts, JSF like MVC framework in .Net

Tags: java, .net, model-view-controller

I am from J2EE background and recently started looking into .Net. I am wondering if .Net have Struts, JSF like MVC framework available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET does have the [MVC framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/) which I think you'll find very comparable to struts.

.NET MVC is really more like the Ruby on Rails framework than struts, but you should find it pretty easy to pick up if you know struts as well.

In struts you have actions, in .NET MVC you have controllers which serve roughly the same purpose - think multiple related struts actions in a single class, with each action being a method on the controller class.  You also have master pages which correspond roughly to tiles in struts.

Comment: Wow I never knew ASP.net tries to fork RoR.

Comment: @jpartogi - the language of course is completely different, but the ideas of models, views & controllers with action methods and implicit configuration all seem to come straight out of rails.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ASP.Net MVC](http://asp.net/mvc) framework, somewhat similar to struts